# centering the table with tabular*

Tags: tables

How can I centre the table content?

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
  \caption{The Vehicle types}
  \label{tab:table3}
\begin{tabular*}{8cm}{p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}
  \hline
\bfseries Vehicle Type & \bfseries Accel\& Decel & \bfseries Sigma & \bfseries Max Speed & \bfseries Probability\\
\hline\hline
Fast & 4/6 & 0.2 & 36 m/s &  10\%\\
Normal &  2/4 & 0.3 & 28 m/s &  80\% \\
Slow &  2/4 & 0.5 & 20 m/s &  10\% \\
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the second `table` environment inside the first, which is an error. To centre the contents such as the `tabular*` use `\centering` at the start of the `table` environment.

Using `[h]` make it likely that the table goes to the end of the document as it stops LaTeX placing the float in almost all available places. If you must use the optional argument you probably want `[htp]`.

Also

```
\begin{tabular*}{8cm}{p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}
```

can not work, it specifies a target width but does not allow the table to expand. Just use

```
\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}}
```

Or (if you must)

```
\begin{tabular*}{8cm}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}@{}}
```

Answer (score 3):

I adjusted your table to make it look more fancy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{The Vehicle types}
    \label{tab:table2}
    \begin{tabular}{rSSSS}
        \toprule    
        \textbf{Vehicle Type} & \textbf{Accel \& Decel} & \textbf{Sigma} & \textbf{Max Speed} & \textbf{Probability} \\
                              &                         &                & [\si{\metre\per\second}]    & [\si{\percent}] \\
        \midrule
        {Fast}   & {4/6} & 0.2 & 36 & 10 \\
        {Normal} & {2/4} & 0.3 & 28 & 80 \\
        {Slow}   & {2/4} & 0.5 & 20 & 10 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image]